# Filter output of Gradle's dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies

#### Maven

In Maven, when performing a `mvn dependency:tree` you can specify a filter argument like so:

`-Dincludes=<groupId>:artifactId>`

(See [filtering a dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html))

### Gradle

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent option for the `dependencies` command in Gradle.

Is there way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only filtering option available is for a configuration:

```
gradle <your-module>:dep --configuration compile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `depdendencyInsight` task to achieve something close to what you are looking for. However, it may *not* be the same as what maven's `dependency:tree` can produce.

Refer :  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html

Assuming your build.gradle has multiple configurations -

```
configuratuion{
   compile
   scm
}
```

In order to filter library say `commons-codec`, for each configuration, you could run the following -

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency commons-codec --configuration scm    
gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency commons-codec --configuration compile
```

As of Gradle 4.9, this is what I have observed -

- the parameter `--dependency` is mandatory
- only 1 value can be provided for `--dependency`
- the parameter `--configuration` is optional
- the default value of `--configuration` is `compileClasspath`